# PDO_SQLSRV returns no error, cant insert values

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I want to insert values to MS SQL using PHP PDO prepared statement, I am sure I am successfully connected to SQL Server, But I have no Idea why can't I insert data on it.

This is how I connect to SQL server

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1 align='center'>Paycom Projects</h1>
    <h5 align='center'>Paycom CRUD</h5><br/>
    <?php
      $serverName = "EDGEWEBMEDIA-PC\SQLEXPRESS";

        /* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
        try
         {
           $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=paycom",  "sa", "edgeweb");
           $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
         }
        catch(Exception $e)
        { 
           die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
        }
```

insert.php

```
<?php

            include_once('connect.php');

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO employee (firstname, lastname, email) 
                VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
                $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

                // insert a row
                $firstname = "John";
                $lastname = "Doe";
                $email = "john@example.com";
                $stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));

                // insert another row
                $firstname = "Mary";
                $lastname = "Moe";
                $email = "mary@example.com";
                $stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));

                // insert another row
                $firstname = "Julie";
                $lastname = "Dooley";
                $email = "julie@example.com";
                $stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));

                echo "New records created successfully";
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            $conn = null;
```

What is wrong with this? I already tried this using a Framework(Laravel) in the same machine, and it work flawlessly, But I want to test this using plain php(no framework) .

Tables, columns is manually added through sql management studio

**UPDATE**

Now I know the exact error is, as I added

```
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Now the error is related to null id values

```
  [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id',
```

My updated question is, do I have prevent this error?

**Update**

Now I am able to insert data by modifying the table, id field is set to nullabler, but I know this not acceptable since we need id for every data in table when performing query

Answer (score 1):

Got it

This is how I solved it

Drop the table and recreate

```
    set id as not null, primary, and auto increment
```

Then in design

```
Under Indentity Specification, set (Is Identity)=Yes and Indentity Increment=1
```

That's it